# Reinstallng Mathematica 9

Tags: installation

I have used Mathematica 9 for long time. Recently I have upgraded my operating system to Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to reinstall Mathematica 9. It did not give any error while installing. However when i try to open Mathematica to complete registration, it give the output

> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica:
>   /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1:
>   version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)

I don't understand what is wrong, as the same machine with Ubuntu 17.04 it installed perfectly and never gave a problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: "*Any suggestions?*" install MMA 11.3?

Comment: Mathematica 9 came out almost a decade ago. Ubuntu 18.04, this year. It is expected that very old software might be incompatible with very new software. Sucks when it happens, but that means it's time to upgrade!

Comment: *Mathematica 9 came out almost a decade ago* Damn. Now I feel old.

Comment: @NikiEstner Actually, it came out in 2012 and they sold it until 2014. So it's only been four years since they stopped selling it, so don't feel too old :)

Comment: As a example from another OS, using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, I have versions 6,7,8,9,10 installed and they all work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem after having upgraded to Fedora 30. A similar issue has already been discussed here

[Can't launch Mathematica 11 on Fedora 29](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189306/cant-launch-mathematica-11-on-fedora-29)

And the solution for this particular problem can be found e.g. in

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375927

Essentially, all you need to do is just copy `libz.so.1` from your `/usr/lib` to the relevant Mathematica directory

```
sudo cp Mathematica9Path/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1 Mathematica9Path/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1.old
sudo cp /usr/lib/libz.so.1 Mathematica9Path/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/
```