# Can't launch Mathematica 11 on Fedora 29

Tags: linux, installation

I've tried installing Mathematica 11 on Fedora 29 using the .sh install file. The installation seems to have worked (no errors and everything looks normal). However, when I attempt to run Mathematica I get the following error

/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var

Seems to be some sort of font error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had same problem on different Linux. I will show what I did.

This is a known issue.  see https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/57948

> Problems with fontconfig and Mathematica. The following error is
>   reported.
>   /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.2/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica:
>   symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol:
>   FT_Done_MM_Var

What I did is this: become root, and removed 3 libs related to this error, from inside Mathematica system folder. To be safe, you can rename them instead.

Remove or rename  **freetype.so.** and I remember also removing **libz.so.**

Here is the main link I used to help with this.

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8198000.html?sid=ab27c1ca8e1927691858595185e18284

I switched back to windows for desktop since then.

I did send bug report to WRI on this. CASE:**4082638** This is the reply I got

> This may be related to a known issue and the developers are working on
>   resolving it for a future Mathematica version. In the meantime, please
>   consider placing libfreetype.so.6 in
>   the MathematicaInstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/
>   directory. The libfreetype.so.6 component is available at
>   https://wolfr.am/vO0qvWH7PW: Another option is reverting
>   back to fontconfig 2.12. Please let us know if neither option
>   resolves the behavior. Wolfram Technical
>   Supportsupport.wolfram.com

btw, I did not follow the instructions in the email above, since by the time I got the reply, the problem was resolved by deleting these libraries mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks you. I had previously tried renaming `libfreetype.so` and `libfreetype.so.6`, which didn't help. But now I also renamed `libz.so.1`, and that seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: As answer above suggests I copied from /usr/lib/** **libz.so.1** and **libfreetype.so.6** to
MathematicaInstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/ and it started working.

Comment: Thanks now mathematica start, but adding a subchapter leads to an error/wrong formating. ;-(

Comment: @JoKalliauer Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by `adding a subchapter leads to an error/wrong formating` If you mean you were above to start Mathematica now OK, but you have an issue using afterwords, then I would suggest making a new question on that. Myself do not use Mathematica on Linux. But on windows now.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer indeed +1, but the short-link you provided for the library appears to be broken

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS. It worked for me just renaming libfreetype.so, libfreetype.so.6 and libz.so.1

Comment: I had the same issue with Mathematica 11.1 after an ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, then I renamed libfreetype.so , libfreetype.so.6 and libz.so.1 as explained above but Mathematica is not starting, the error message is: Mathematica: cairo-scaled-font.c:459: _cairo_scaled_glyph_page_destroy: Assertion `!scaled_font->cache_frozen' failed.
Aborted (core dumped) LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found -- (LinkObject[j8pck_shm, 3, 1]) The link proposed by Wolfram : https://wolfr.am/vO0qvWH7PW is not working Please help

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question here. You should contact wolfram support for such issues.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96237)

Answer (score 1):

All solutions here did not work for me. However, this did work:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mathematica#Troubleshooting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

On 5.13.13-arch1-1 updated september 1 of 2021 fails this solution, after searching doesn't find solution I copy previous version of libz and libfreetype with mathematica working and copy and paste into Mathematica-FOLDER/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64 and mathematica works again

you can get these ones here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z0ExZtxmAJ4AXOUEm085tLdL141dladn?usp=sharing